# what am I doing wrong w/ this SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

When I run this it doesn't throw an error however it doesn't insert/delete an entry either. I don't know why it's not working.

```
DECLARE @trAction VARCHAR(5)
  SET @trAction = 'addTR'

  IF EXISTS (SELECT TransgeneID
            FROM tbl_MT
            WHERE MouseID = '3' AND TransgeneID = '3')
    IF (@trAction = 'rmvTR')    
      DELETE
      FROM tbl_MT
      WHERE MouseID = '3' AND TransgeneID = '3'
  ELSE
    IF (@trAction = 'addTR')  
      INSERT INTO tbl_MT 
      VALUES ('3', '3')
```

Comment: And does exist a row where `MouseID = '3' AND TransgeneID = '3'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, put `BEGIN` and `END` on the `IF's`:

```
  DECLARE @trAction VARCHAR(5)
  SET @trAction = 'addTR'

  IF EXISTS (SELECT TransgeneID
            FROM tbl_MT
            WHERE MouseID = '3' AND TransgeneID = '3')
  BEGIN
    IF (@trAction = 'rmvTR')    
    BEGIN
      DELETE
      FROM tbl_MT
      WHERE MouseID = '3' AND TransgeneID = '3'
    END
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    IF (@trAction = 'addTR')  
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO tbl_MT 
      VALUES ('3', '3')
    END
  END
```

**Second and final, if the first `IF` is true, the inner `IF (@trAction = 'rmvTR')` will fail and nothing will be done.**

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. After the {BEGIN} and {END} are in, it works. And when first {IF} is true and inner {IF (@trAction = 'rmvTR')} I want it to, doing nothing. That was intentional. But good eye and thanks for bringing it up for my attention.

Comment: @MadushM no problem, is just for others see what the problem was if they have the same :)